# Querying a billion rows in sql server with a quick response time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table having 300 columns and approx a billion rows of data. I need to query such data with a very very quick response time (I did it SQL and end up with unsatisified users). I started researching last year and tried cassandra, mongoDB, Olap and SQL Server. I had no luck with any of them, I admit if had paid little more attention things would be different now but I have no option but to ask here. Having a SQL background I need to do it in SQL for obvious reasons.

I got three servers, each having

- OS: Windows 2008 64-bit
- SQL Server 2008
- CPU: 2x Xeon E5420 (8 cores total)
- RAM: 24 GB
- HDD RAID: 2 TB

Any suggestions on hardware, database solutions? Please forgive me if this doesn't make any sense.

Thanks!

**Edit 1** : I got a PK on `id` column, each column has a non clustered index. Queries are simple - a mix of several ANDs/ORs:

```
Select count(*) 
from tbl 
where (col1 = value1 AND col2 in (value1, value2) AND...) 
  and (col1 = value1 OR col2 in (value1, value2) OR...)
```

**Edit 2** : The table contains consumer data name, address, state, email etc. I have tried splitting them and querying them in parallel apart from above listed solutions.

**Edit 3** : I am expecting 3 to 4 users using the site at a time.

Comment: You need to provider more details, including what you've tried and the specific problem you're having: without knowing anything about your schema, what indices you have on the table(s) and the details of your query, it's impossible to answer the question. If your query gets a seek on the clustered index, you'll likely get a pretty instantaneous response. If it has to table scan, your stuck with O(n) time.

Comment: If you have 1 table with 300 columns and a billion rows - then most likely your DB structure is wrong.  Server specs aren't going to fix that. Setting up your tables correctly will.  You need to post details of the tables (including keys and indexes), the queries you have trouble with and the number of expected results. Before we can give you any suggestions.

Comment: @NicholasCarey Added a sample query, seems i need to learn few things before writing here.

Comment: Downvoters : I was evaluating/trying solutions since last october,approx a year now.I didnt ask before unless I was sure I cant get around it.Before posting SO warned me of getting blocked and you guys added to the party.Thanks and I appreciate you guys for coming down to help

Answer (score 2):

This'll likely be closed as a software request question...but three options and a comment:

comment - 300 columns wide and a billion+ deep is a messy table...you will want to have an ETL process that reads this table and normalizes the structre a bit (think data warehouse...fact and dimension tables).  Any reports that are requesting aggregated data can have those aggreates run nightly and saved...if the same aggregate is running over and over again, save time and resources by doing that aggregate during off hours.

that said, there are three 'high volume' databases that are designed for billions of rows (possibly more, but I'm not that aware of them.  SQL only, not going into nosql for you):

Vertica (HP's offering)- This will run on existing hardware pretty readily.  It's a column store database, which works fundamentally differently than the standard database.  The logic on cardinality really lets vertica fly...very clever solution and I think cheapest of what I'll recommend.

Netezza (IBM's offering) - this is an appliance (a stand alone machine) that you can purchase.  They put FPGA (basically a processor) on each physical hard drive...sort of a brute force approach.  Downside is you are buying hardward here, not just an install on existing machine.

Exadata (Oracle's offering)- Oracles alternative to Netezza...same theory, using brute force in hardware along with some processor logic to increase access speeds.  Warning here is once you are in with Oracle, you're in with Oracle...expect the cost of the machine to double yearly (keep an eye on 'lifetime cost' and not just installation cost).

I went with Vertica after a long evaluation...the logic solution of a columnar database appealed to me over using a massive hardware solution.  Doing spatial queries (lat/lon lookups) were able to go through 4 billion records and locate if the point I was searching for was in that lat/lon range...about 2-3 seconds to search for an item in all 4 billion rows.  Also the lack of defining indexes was a nice bonus (the columnar database style is self indexing)

edit:
I went to a vendor for each of the three above...I recommend doing the same, these guys will shmooze ya to no end ^^

Comment: Vertica looks promising.Reading docs! I will give a try this weekend.Tysm.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Solid State Drives to improve performance here. Disk IOPS is a significant factor in database performance.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your answer may not lie with SQL. One detail you left out was the load you are expecting on your SQL database. SQL is not a distributed creature, thus you can only scale up your server hardware to try and meet your needs.

Fortunately, there are options for scaling out, but it would go against your requirement to stay in SQL. You may consider utilizing a caching layer to free up some of the stress on the SQL server, or perhaps even use the cache for querying if you use a smart caching solution. What is nice about adding a caching layer on top of SQL is that you can scale out your cache to handle increased load. Caching will also be extremely fast due to the in-memory nature of it. I suggest at least considering a caching layer to see if it might meet your needs.

Since you have already looked at Cassandra and MongoDB, you may have noticed some other similar products out there. Here are some caching options:

[Redis](http://redis.io/)

[AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312(v=azure.10).aspx)

[ScaleOut StateServer](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/products/scaleout-stateserver/)

[NCache](http://www.google.com)

[ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) (may not be suitable for your needs)

**EDIT 1**:

I am curious if you have determined your bottleneck already (CPU, memory, network, limitations of SQL)? Also, can you give some specifics as to the amount of time it takes to run your queries -- how long they take versus how long you want/need them to take? Also, how large are your row objects (in bytes/kilobytes)?

Either way, you still might benefit from using caching of some sort, be it a [SQL-level cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx) or another layer on top (as mentioned before). The main thing I worry about is storing a billion cache objects in memory; you may have to implement an LRU cache or similar.

Another option could be to cache the queries and responses to your SQL database. This might be a better option given your criteria; however, memory still would be of concern.